# INSERT from a SELECT combined with a single value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, insert

I have this query that returns several rows of `item_id`:

```
select item_id from properties where name like 'body';
```

And I have the second one that returns 1 row of `tag_id`:

```
select id from tags where name ilike '%hoax%';
```

I want to use both results to create new rows in a third table `item_tags` so that I can insert each `item_id` from the first query with the `tag_id` from the second query.

I'll have something like:

```
INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id) VALUES (item_id1, tag_id);  
INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id) VALUES (item_id2, tag_id);
INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id) VALUES (item_id3, tag_id);   
 ...
```

The 1st query returns over 800 rows. How can I automate the insert?
psql 9.1.11, Postgres 9.1.4.

Comment: You can use `INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id) SELECT ...` Just write the appropriate select query that combines the two you have into a 2 column select.

Comment: thanks. If you answer the question i can vote for it. here is what i did `INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id) select * from (select item_id from properties where name like 'body') a, ( select id as tag_id from tags where name ilike '%hoax%') b;`

Comment: Please note that if you have 100 item_ids and 200 tag_ids, you will be inserting 100*200 records.

Comment: Aside: Why the version mismatch between psql and Postgres? It's recommended that you always [upgrade to the latest point release of the major version in use - and that's currently 9.1.13 for 9.1.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Basic `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id)
SELECT p.item_id, t.id
FROM  (SELECT item_id FROM properties WHERE name LIKE 'body') p
    , (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name ILIKE '%hoax%') t
```

Where the comma (`,`) in the FROM clause is short notation for [**`CROSS JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

That's building on your assertion that the second query on `tags` ...

> returns 1 row of `tag_id`

You get a Cartesian Product from a `CROSS JOIN`, that's n*m combinations.
If both sides of the join return more than one row, they multiply each other.
If either side does not return a row, the overall result is *no row* and nothing happens.
If you want neither of those effects, one side must return ***at least one*** row, and the other side ***exactly one*** row.

For your specific combination you can also use a nested subselect:

```
INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id)
SELECT item_id 
     , (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name ILIKE '%hoax%') AS tag_id  -- single result!
FROM   properties
WHERE  name LIKE 'body';
```

***The subtle difference:*** This inserts all rows returned from the outer `SELECT`, even if the subselect on `tags` returns no row, which would be converted to **`NULL`** for `tag_id`.

#### Bulk `INSERT`

To deal with lots of such inserts at once, you would use a **largely modified query**. But the same rules as for the first query above apply for cardinalities in both joined tables.

```
INSERT INTO item_tags (item_id, tag_id)
SELECT p.item_id, t.id
FROM  (
   VALUES
      ('body',  'hoax')
    , ('body2', 'fun')
    , ('body3', 'love')
  ) AS it(item, tag)
JOIN   properties p ON p.name LIKE it.item
JOIN   tags t ON t.name ILIKE ('%' || it.tag ||'%');
```

You see the logic, right? Personally, I call this a "`CROSS JOIN` by proxy".

Comment: I love the "cross join by proxy" from today, it executes our 160000 rows sql under one second. On pg 10 it took 8 seconds, and on pg 11 it crashed the server on out of memory (it used nested subselect) after 8 seconds. Cross join by proxy is fast, readable and completely beautiful! :-)